# Two installation of Magento 2.1.7 each has a completely diff style-l.css

Tags: magento-2.1.7

Anyone know why or came across where 2 installations of the same version have different styles especially the width of columns? e.g `.page-layout-?
columns .sidebar-main` changed from  `20.83333333%;` to `16.66666667%;` which is quite considerably to me.

I've installed about 2 months ago 2.1.7 on my local server.
Now I have installed same version 2.1.7 on a remote server but this file totally different and I can tell I have not changed any of this core files.
Here is is link diff [diffchecker](https://www.diffchecker.com/VJufTeh9).

Thank's.

Comment: @Nikunj Vadarya thank's for the edit suggestion, most importantly do you have any information why this have changed or heard of?

Comment: which theme you are selected

Comment: both setup are luma theme?

Comment: @Sagar, I have my custom module set up parent like this.
<parent>Magento/luma</parent>. Yes both of them

Comment: Ooh I found something that could help debug this.
I notice when I run php bin/magento setup:upgrade then style-l.css changed back that means if you check the [diffchecker](https://www.diffchecker.com/VJufTeh9) it's using the one on the right. with smaller width.

Comment: Are you create your custom theme?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/63310/discussion-between-juliano-vargas-and-sagar-dobariya).

Answer (score 0):

Ok I found out why it was changing the style-l.css.
So there a tiny bit of discrepancy there on my local server I had in my web folder custom theme `web/css/source/_theme.less` and I had changed the `@button__background` but I did not have `_theme.less` on the remote server.
Now there is another question which is why when I have `web/css/source/_theme.less` file in my custom theme the styles also change s even if there is nothing in it?